# How to roll back failed gparted ext4 partition growth

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext4

I had a 12TB ext4 partition which I wanted to extend to 18TB.
I've added the new disks to the RAID and after doing that
I wanted to re-size the partition to occupy this new space.
I started the growth of the partition but the procedure failed
because the ext4 cannot handle partitions bigger than 16TB.

The problem is that now when I open gparted, gparted shows that the
size of the partition is 18TB but I can see only 12TB in Nautilus window.

How can I roll back the effects of the gparted operation
so the two sizes are consistent with each other?

The output of gparted error:

```
    GParted 0.12.1 --enable-libparted-dmraid

Libparted 2.3
Grow /dev/sda1 from 12.73 TiB to 18.19 TiB  00:25:00    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda1
start: 2,048
end: 27,341,617,151
size: 27,341,615,104 (12.73 TiB)
check file system on /dev/sda1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:12:46    ( SUCCESS )

e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

3170078 inodes used (0.74%, out of 427212800)
187157 non-contiguous files (5.9%)
439 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
Extent depth histogram: 3167183/2814/2
3159801838 blocks used (92.45%, out of 3417701888)
0 bad blocks
187 large files

3057556 regular files
112442 directories
0 character device files
0 block device files
0 fifos
0 links
71 symbolic links (71 fast symbolic links)
0 sockets
------------
3170069 files
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
grow partition from 12.73 TiB to 18.19 TiB  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

old start: 2,048
old end: 27,341,617,151
old size: 27,341,615,104 (12.73 TiB)
new start: 2,048
new end: 39,059,453,951
new size: 39,059,451,904 (18.19 TiB)
check file system on /dev/sda1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:12:14    ( SUCCESS )

e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

3170078 inodes used (0.74%, out of 427212800)
187157 non-contiguous files (5.9%)
439 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
Extent depth histogram: 3167183/2814/2
3159801838 blocks used (92.45%, out of 3417701888)
0 bad blocks
187 large files

3057556 regular files
112442 directories
0 character device files
0 block device files
0 fifos
0 links
71 symbolic links (71 fast symbolic links)
0 sockets
------------
3170069 files
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
grow file system to fill the partition  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

resize2fs /dev/sda1

resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
resize2fs: New size too large to be expressed in 32 bits

========================================
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the command line utility gdisk to re-set the GPT partition to the following values (start: 2,048, end: 27,341,617,151).  The start and end values are from the gparted_details.htm log file that you provided.